# Evaluating tf.py_func in session.run() returns "Invalid type list"

Tags: python, tensorflow

My data is arranged in structure:

```
data/
  good/
  bad/
```

with each subfolder containing jpg files.
I'm trying to create an input pipeline that would accept `basepath` as input and construct an `image_op` and `label_op`. Evaluating these would give me an (image, label) tuple, e.g.:

```
image, label = session.run([image_op, label_op])
```

To get a label for a given image I must look at its image path. One simple solution is to do:

```
label = int("good" in path)
```

There isn't any support for such string operation in tensorflow that I'm aware of (v0.9), so I thought to use `tf.py_func` wrapper over a simple function like above. However, while evaluating a label op that way succeeds, when trying to evaluate both image path op and label op that uses image path op as input in the same `session.run()`, I get errors.

Here's my python function and tf graph code:

```
def get_label(path):
    return int("good" in str(path))

class DataReadingGraph:
    """
    Graph for reading images into a data queue.
    """

    def __init__(self, base_path):
        """
        Construct the queue
        :param base_path: path to base directory that contains good images and bad images
        subdirectories. They in turn can contain further subdirectories.
        :return:
        """

        # tf can't handle recursive files matching (as of version 0.9), so
        # solve that with glob and just pass globbed paths to a constant
        pattern = os.path.join(base_path, "**/*.jpg")
        filenames = tf.constant(glob.glob(pattern, recursive=True))

        filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames, shuffle=True)
        reader = tf.IdentityReader()
        self.key, self.value = reader.read(filename_queue)

        self.label = tf.py_func(get_label, [self.key], [tf.int64])
```

Now if I run

```
label = session.run(data_reading_graph.label)
```

all is well and I get the label as expected. But if I run

```
key, label = session.run([data_reading_graph.key, data_reading_graph.label])
```

instead, I get

```
<class 'TypeError'>
Fetch argument [<tf.Tensor 'PyFunc:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=int64>] of [<tf.Tensor 'PyFunc:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=int64>] has invalid type <class 'list'>, must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a list into a Tensor or Operation.)
```

I don't really understand what went wrong here, what got converted into a list though it shouldn't, and why I can't evaluate key op and label op in the same `session.run()`.

I can try to do labels extraction in pure Python code before starting tf graph, but the problem remains - why can't I evaluate `py_func` and its input in the same `session.run()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.py_func` returns a **list** of Tensors.

You should just get `self.label = self.label[0]`:

```
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames, shuffle=True)
    reader = tf.IdentityReader()
    self.key, self.value = reader.read(filename_queue)

    self.label = tf.py_func(get_label, [self.key], [tf.int64])[0]
```

Comment: Oh dear, you are totally right. I feel so silly right now... Thank you.

Comment: At first I thought it was a real bug in `tf.py_func` but no :)